# Clarification on SFMC Send Classifications and how many are needed

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email

I work in a medium sized business and we have several email audiences - basically, 3 overall audiences, with a few different subsets of each of those 3. We're in the education sector so you can think of the three like students/teachers/universities.

We send some operational messages and some commercial messages. Generally the commercial messaging only goes to one of the audiences.

However, we have over 20 send classifications. I was just looking for some perspective on how many send classifications is too many? This seems like an awful lot and I'm convinced we have some we don't use.

Would anyone mind explaining to me exactly how send classifications work? I find them a little confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A send classification (SC) is basically 3 things:

1. Type of messaging [MT] (Transactional vs. Commercial)
2. Sender Profile [SP] (From Name/Address and Replyto instructions)
3. Delivery Profile [DP] (IP address and default header/footer)

The SC is really just an object that simplifies the send process by grouping together these 3 objects into a single object.

This will allow you to:

- Reduce the risk of missing or incorrectly assigning a SP, DP or MT
- Increase simplicity of send flow for less experienced users
- Easy reference for API email send calls
- Allow a universal reference point on what info was used in each send without looking up each individual object (easier reporting/tracking)

As to how many you should use and what is too much, that is really a personal preference.  I usually stick to around 5, but that is because I send to a single brand with simple campaigns - I have known people with upwards of 50 SC to match all the branding, products and message types they require.

20 does sound high from your description, so it is definitely worth a look to see if they are necessary - BUT I wouldn't be surprised if they are all needed either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think whoever set them up here conflated them with publication list so we seemed to almost have one for every different type of message we send!